# content type not listed in drupal views

Tags: database, drupal, view, profile, repair

Trying to reset up a view in Drupal 7.18 for data in profile2 but when go to add content type, the profile type content is not listed to add.

I think I may have broken the table regarding this because it was working before I changed something and views reported something missing but still showed alright in preview of view but not on page of view where it just showed index list. I tried to fix things by deleting the view and starting again but as I said, profile 2 content type won't even show up.

Is there a way around having to restore with full backup because my last backup I've just realised included this error. Is there a way to repair or import just the profile 2 table (from another backup )?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a 'user' view type, you may have to set up a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a view of "Profile Types".